# Ubuntu 20.04, building patched kernel results in no ZFS support

Tags: kernel, zfs

Due to hardware issues I find myself needing to add a patch to the Ubuntu 20.04 kernel.

I downloaded the kernel with:

```
git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal
```

After applying the patch, and ensuring that `do_zfs = true` I built the kernel package.

```
cd focal
cp /boot/config-5.4.0-42-generic .config
make oldconfig
make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg -j8 --initrd --revision=1.0.custom kernel_image
sudo apt install ../linux-image-5.4.44+_1.0.custom_amd64.deb
```

Now when I boot into this new kernel I get

```
Failed to load ZFS modules.
Manually load the modules and exit.
```

NOTE: Manually loading the modules does not work.

What am I doing wrong which is causing the kernel not to be built with ZFS support?  I basically need the default Ubuntu 20.04 kernel as is but with a small patch.

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu kernels have the ZFS drivers built-in to the kernel package by default. If you use your own custom kernel then you need to install the ZFS drivers using the zfs-dkms package.  This is the same package that is imported into the ubuntu kernel package build, so it should provide you the same core ZFS kernel support.

Install the zfs-dkms package as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install zfs-dkms
```

This may take some time to build the module. You also need the kernel headers associated with your kernel package to be installed otherwise dkms may fail to build.